# Facebook SDK email and gender is given Null in android

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-asynctask, facebook-sdk-4.0

Dear developers I'm try to save data from Facebook I'm getting other all data but can't get the email and gender.

This is my code

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile");
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");


    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest( loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {
                    if (response != null) {
                        try {
                            email = object.getString("email");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            gender = object.getString("gender");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "email,gender");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();


            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

            userid = profile.getId();
            userfirstname = profile.getFirstName();
            middlename = profile.getMiddleName();
            userlastname = profile.getLastName();
            userimage = profile.getProfilePictureUri(30, 40);
            linkuri = profile.getLinkUri();
            name = profile.getName();




            new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                    WebService ws = new WebService(URL);
                    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    data.put("user_fb_id", userid);
                    data.put("first_name", userfirstname);
                    data.put("middle_name", userfirstname);
                    data.put("gender", gender);
                    data.put("email", email);
                    data.put("last_name", userfirstname);
                    data.put("user_fb_profile_name", name);
                    data.put("fb_profile_pic", userimage.toString());


                    try {
                        String response = ws.makeHTTPRequest(data, "POST");
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        Log.e("Response", jsonObject.toString());

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("", "Exception : " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            }.execute();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            //info = ("Login attempt canceled.");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            // info = ("Login attempt failed.");
        }
    });
```

now I will let you know what is the error in my above code.

when i run the **GraphRequest** it will execute successfully but didn't get the email and gender. The email and gender is equal to null After the **GrapRequest** method i am running **AsyncTask** and send that data in my web services post class my class give me error of null email and gender but when i hover the email and gender after execution of **AsyncTask** they have that data please help me how to solve that issue.

what i want i want to store the user basic data if there is another way also let me know that i will try.

Comment: In some cases, though user has provided an email, it will not come through request, if the email is not valid.

Comment: you right about the email but i my case the email is have there and it's getting from request but After the AsyncTask  execution . i want to get it before from AsyncTask execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because In your code two Asynctask runs simultaneously.
Means that the GraphRequest class also runs an asynctask to get user data and you are also running a async to send the user data to server.

Async tasks always runs on separate thread(not on Main thread) and they don't wait for completion of other task.

So the solution is call your Async task in onCompleted() method. LIKE..

Write this async class for upload data to server outside of registerCallback.

```
private class Upload_Data extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
 @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                WebService ws = new WebService(URL);
                Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
                data.put("user_fb_id", userid);
                data.put("first_name", userfirstname);
                data.put("middle_name", userfirstname);
                data.put("gender", gender);
                data.put("email", email);
                data.put("last_name", userfirstname);
                data.put("user_fb_profile_name", name);
                data.put("fb_profile_pic", userimage.toString());


                try {
                    String response = ws.makeHTTPRequest(data, "POST");
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    Log.e("Response", jsonObject.toString());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("", "Exception : " + e.getMessage());
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
```

then call this async class in onCompleted method after getting the email and gender value and also check that email and gender is not null before calling Asynctask class.

```
@Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {
                if (response != null) {
                    try {
                        email = object.getString("email");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        gender = object.getString("gender");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
  if(email!=null && gender!=null){
new Upload_Data().execute();
}
            }
        });
```

Hope this will helpful.

Comment: this is not work i paste my post AsyncTask in **onActivityResult** but result is same...

Comment: can you tell me what is the different in my code and your code

Comment: In my code the upload user data Async call after completion of GraphRequest in onCompleted method which calls after getting response from GraphRequest and read my complete answer again then you will understands exactly difference.

Comment: the above code work for me but the method is little change i will edit your code you will approve the edit so that will help other developers

Comment: Bro your edited code and my code are same. I made a different class for UploadAsynctask and calls in onCompleted method which reduces code complexity.